# How to re-use projects in SonarQube

Tags: azure, jenkins, sonarqube

We have multiple repos and whenever the developer runs the sonarQube scanner through Jenkins job, it is creating one project with build number along with the date, is there anyway I can re-use the same project name ..?

developers are running sonarQube reports through Jenkins jobs.

```
sonar.projectKey=portal1-sonar:1stiteration-${BUILD_NUMBER}
sonar.projectName=SonarQube nodeJS portal1 Build : ${BUILD_NUMBER}_${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
```

anyway, I can change and use same project name, whenever developer runs sonarQube.

Answer (score 1):

every project is defined in SonarQube with it's own key. That means if the key is the same, it is the same Project, and you will have a "history" of analyses and can compare parameters.

Although the idea of buildnumbers seems to be interesting, i recommend to use Branch names instead. There are currently two ways of doing this, for the first one, you need to have a SonarQube installation with a paid price. Than you are entitled to use the branch plugin. Which is actually the more superior way, because your project will show branches. The [sonarQube docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/branches/overview/) are quiet helpful regarding this.

The old/Deprecated way will create a new project per branch, which you can than compare. the property you need to set is `sonar.branch` and this will be automatically added to your project key. So if the project key is `Project` and the `sonar.branch` is set to `develop` your new project will have the key `Project:develop`. This parameter is deprecated, and i am not sure, how long it will stay in the system.